# My WordPress site is not tracked by Google Analytics anymore

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

I have changed my WordPress theme. Suddenly I could see that Google Analytics is not tracking anymore for the past two days.

How to re-verify that? Also I have enable tracking code in *All in one SEO plugin* today?

Answer (score 1):

By changing your WordPress theme, it's possible it removed the Google Analytics tracking code from your website.

To be sure your site will be tracked again, you can verify that the HTML code of your site has this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

If it's not the case, check your new theme to see if you can indicate your Google Analytics account or add the code below in your header or footer (if you do this last procedure, change the XXXXXXXX by your Google Analytics id).

By the way, I don't how you could enable the Google Anatycis tracking code from the *All in one SEO plugin*, I personally can't do it for my sites.